# Rolling COUNT DISTINCT of n-day active users using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am counting 7-day active users using **T-SQL**. I used the following code:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT [UserID]) OVER (
        PARTITION BY [HospitalID], [HospitalName], [Device]
        ORDER BY [Date]
        ROWS 7 PRECEDING
    ) AS [7-Day Active Users]
FROM UserActivity
ORDER BY [HospitalID], [HospitalName], [Device], [Date]
```

I was told `Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause`.
`UserActivity` is a table with columns `HospitalID`, `HospitalName`, `Device` (either phone or tablet), `Date` and `UserID` (could be NULL). To make things easier, I have filled the gaps between dates which made `Date` consecutive so I can use `ROWS 7 PRECEDING` with confidence. I did a lot of searches online and found most solution are either using other types of SQL (which is not possible in my case) or using `DENSE_RANK` function which does not support a moving window. What is the correct and hopefully simpler, concise way of solving my problem?

Sample Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19vrBK8ixpiPJycRjb1ekiKnEUYk5AaUH/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110206477774349430845&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Sample data (as text) and expected results would help immensely here

Comment: @Charlieface, sorry I have added the link to my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to see that `COUNT DISTINCT` was not supported in that type of SQL... I hadn't known that. Especially after you went to the trouble of fixing the gaps between dates!

I used [Rasgo](https://www.rasgoml.com/data-analysis-tutorials) to generate the SQL -- so this won't work directly in your version (tested with Snowflake), but I think it will work as long as you fix the `DATEADD` function. Every RDBMS seems to do `DATEADD` differently, it seems.

The general concept here is to join the data upon itself using a `range join` condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Luckily, this should work for you without having to fix the gaps in the dates first.

```
WITH BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY AS (
  SELECT 
    A.HOSPITALNAME, 
    A.HOSPITALID, 
    A.DEVICE, 
    A.DATE, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT B.USERID) as COUNT_DISTINCT_USERID_PAST7DAY, 
    COUNT(1) AS AGG_ROW_COUNT 
  FROM 
    UserActivity A 
    INNER JOIN UserActivity B ON A.HOSPITALNAME = B.HOSPITALNAME 
    AND A.HOSPITALID = B.HOSPITALID 
    AND A.DEVICE = B.DEVICE 
  WHERE 
    B.DATE >= DATEADD(day, -7, A.DATE) 
    AND B.DATE <= A.DATE 
  GROUP BY 
    A.HOSPITALNAME, 
    A.HOSPITALID, 
    A.DEVICE, 
    A.DATE
) 
SELECT 
  src.*, 
  BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY.COUNT_DISTINCT_USERID_PAST7DAY 
FROM 
  UserActivity src 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY ON BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY.DATE = src.DATE 
  AND BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY.HOSPITALNAME = src.HOSPITALNAME 
  AND BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY.HOSPITALID = src.HOSPITALID 
  AND BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY.DEVICE = src.DEVICE
```

Let me know how that works out and if it doesn't work I'll help you out.

Edit:  For those who are trying to do this and getting stuck, a common mistake (one that I myself performed when I did this by hand) is to pay careful attention to COUNT(DISTINCT(B.col)) and not A.col. When I used Rasgo to generate the SQL to check myself, I caught my mistake. Hopefully this note helps someone in the future who makes this same mistake!

Comment: Sorry, I have added some sample data. I should have done that.

Comment: it seems your solution does not return the correct result. I observed a sudden drop of 7-day active users where it should not be.

Comment: @JamesChang my apologies, I had a mistake and have corrected it now. Please try now

Comment: I would use DATEADD(DAY, -6, A.DATE) according to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6171863?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article. Yesterday, I came up with a solution that uses DENSE_RANK() but the code is very chunky compared to yours. Impressive conciseness!

Comment: This is the code that I used eventually, l left out the left join since it made the execution very slow: SELECT t1.[HospitalID], t1.[HospitalName], t1.[Device], t1.[Date], COUNT(DISTINCT(t2.[UserID])) AS [7-Day Active Users]
FROM UserActivity AS t1
INNER JOIN UserActivity t2
ON t1.[HospitalID] = t2.[HospitalID] AND t1.[HospitalName] = t2.[HospitalName] AND t1.[Device] = t2.[Device]
WHERE t2.[Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -6, t1.[Date]) AND t2.[Date] <= t1.[Date]
GROUP BY t1.[HospitalID], t1.[HospitalName], t1.[Device], t1.[Date]
ORDER BY t1.[HospitalID], t1.[HospitalName], t1.[Device], t1.[Date]